# MySQL PHP - how to display non readable character stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, zend-framework2

I'm working with ZendFramework 2, here is my setting

**./config/autoload/global.php**

```
'db' => array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=littlepinktree;host=localhost',
    'driver_optoins' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
)
```

In database,

[image: non readable character in database]

In web page,

[image: Non readable character showing in web]

The **Collation** is set to `utf8_unicode_ci` and the **Engine** is `MyISAM`

Anyone have any idea how to display this kind of characters in webpage properly?

Comment: which encoding are you using for the html?

Comment: May be better with `driver_options` intead of `driver_optoins`. Besides, with PHP >= 5.3.6, charset can be part of the DSN (`mysql:dbname=littlepinktree;host=localhost;charset=utf8`).

Comment: @julp thanks, is my mistake about spelling error, I didn't realize it. now is able to show exactly the same as in database. Is that possible to correct those non-readable characters in database?

Answer (score 0):

if not already in use you can try to add the charset to the HTML header:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: nothing change even added this line, but before that already got `<meta charset="utf-8">`